# Building a video Streaming App using WebRtc And Along With Peer to peer connection Locally?

Tags: swift3, webrtc, multipeer-connectivity

Is it possible to use the WebRtc Offline. When we connect 2 devices through peer to peer connection After that WebRtc for streaming the video Which we want to set it through offline which we don't want to use the internet for every time. Is this Method is possible to Implement using WebRtc.
How can We set the Quality of the Video using WebRtc. Every time it Works as its Default Quality Streaming. How can we Improve Its Quality.

https://github.com/Mahabali/BonjourWebrtc

I just gone through the Link it is pretty good using WebRtc and Peer to peer Connection. But if the Internet is not their it is not Work. How can I overcome this Problem. Is it possible to set Offline using WebRtc and How I improve the Quality of the Video.

Sorry For my Bad English hope anyone help me to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on the blog of the BonjourWebRtc project : https://mobilitysolutionsexpert.wordpress.com/2016/05/04/server-less-or-no-server-webrtc-ios-app/, it used a Google Stun server.

So if you want to used it offline, you have to host your own Stun server on a local server. You can easily find code for Stun server on the web, juste google it.

Comment: I have searched a lot for that but  I couldn't find it. could you please share one or two links sorry if you don't mind. It will be very Helpful.

Comment: Here are some examples : http://www.stunprotocol.org/ or https://github.com/enobufs/stun

Comment: Can you tel me WebRtc have some Standard camera capture quality? Because while using default camera and webRtc camera lot of difference is their.

Comment: I only deal with WebRTC data channel, so I never used Audio/Video. By the way, video need to be encoded before transmitting. You can maybe change the video encoder profile to increase the quality. Maybe this link https://webrtchacks.com/how-to-figure-out-webrtc-camera-resolutions/ can help you